# Initialising a vector with anoter vector, returned from a function

Tags: c++, vector, file-handling

I'm attempting to create a vector called `mems` which is declared using the returned vector from my `myMembers()` function. For some reason when I use the line:

`vector<string> mems = myMembers();` It returns an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
```

This error doesn't appear at compilation, but instead it appears once the program reaches this line of code. I've been researching for a few hours on what to do to fix it, but I'm really not sure.

The code that I've written so far is as follows:

```
vector<string> Person::myMembers(){
    fstream file;
    file.open("myFile.txt");
    string myLine;
    vector<string> mems;
    

    while(getline(myFile, myLine)){
        vector<string> myLine = split(myLine, ',');
        mems.push_back(myLine.at(0));
        for (int i = 5; i < myLine.size(); i++){
            mems.push_back(myLine.at(i));
        }
    }
    return mems;
}
```

The above function will get the name at index 0, and the list of names from index 5 to n. It will then place these names into a vector called `mems`, and return it.

(I should make you aware that split is a function I've written which will simply split a line by a specified delimiter, and then put it into a vector).

Then, later in my code, I create a new vector, called `mems`, and set it equal to the output of `myMembers()`

`vector<string> mems = myMembers()`

I know that it's the above line of code that's causing the error, but I don't know why, or how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time :)

### Edit

Upon mention that the error might be a part of the splitString, please find the code for my SplitString function below:

```
vector<string> split(string myString, char delimiter){
    string temp = 0;
    vector<string> splitString;

    for (int i = 0; i < myString.size(); i++){
        if (myString[i] != delimiter){
            temp += myString[i];
        } else {
            splitString.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return splitString;
}
```

Comment: Thou shalt not pass a null to the `string` constructor. Exactly where you have done this and how...

Comment: `mems.push_back(myLine.at(0));` is fatal one way or another if the line is empty.

Comment: The error is saying that a `std::string` is being constructed with a `nullptr` as input, but I see no such construction in the code shown, so it has to be in code that is not shown (maybe inside of `split()`, perhaps?). If you run this code in a debugger, it will tell you exactly where the failing `string` is being constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the issue for the program. The split() function was causing the error, because `temp` was initialised as `string temp = 0;` which meant it was trying to initialise a string with an integer value.

The correct code for the split() function is as follows:

```
ector<string> split(string myString, char delimiter){
    string temp = "";
    vector<string> splitString;

    for (int i = 0; i < myString.size(); i++){
        string temp = "";
        if (myString[i] != delimiter){
            temp += myString[i];
        } else {
            splitString.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return splitString;
}
```

This then lets the split() function return a non-null string, and allows the program to run as it should.